# como ler operando maior que 9

Tags: c, array

Como ler um operando composto por 2 ou mais caracteres, no código que eu criei eu percorro toda a `string` a fim de identificar cada tipo de operação e número, só que estou percorrendo esse determinado vetor e tratando cada posição como um caractere(`char`) a parte. Portanto, ao entrar com o valor 10, não seria tratado como um número e sim como 2 caracteres, nesse caso 1 e 0.

**Segue o código:** https://onlinegdb.com/ByCh64VHH

O que eu posso fazer para exibir esse tipo de operando ?

**P.S.:** não quero realizar nenhuma operação, só exibi-lo!

Comment: Em primeiro lugar em C a atribuição de uma string não é feita com o operador = e sim com a função strcpy de <string.h> (ex.: res = "SOMA";). Para identificar números com vários algarismos você tem que analisar sua entrada e identificar e separar os tokens, lembrando que um número pode ser um inteiro ou um real e a notação pode ser normal ou científica, a cada algarismo lido transforme o número acrescentando mais este algarismo à direita.

Comment: Se não necessitar do valor numérico correspondente apenas copie cada algarismo para uma string e quando não houver mais algarismos acrescente o terminador '\0', levando em conta as possíveis notações utilizadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas, como você está tratando cada posição como um caractere você poderia utilizar uma laço ***while*** para analisar todas as posições, e, em cada ciclo do laço você compara caractere com caractere.

Comment: fiz isso e funcionou, deveria ter pensado nisso logo de cara, estou precisando reforçar lógica, pois era uma questão de lógica e nem de sintaxe.